# Saving boostrap WYSIWYG Submitted URI too large using AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to save my bootstrap WYSIWYG content by copying the div editor to a hidden textarea, but when i tried to submit it using ajax, i got a error "Submitted URI too large!" when checked i found out the image that i am trying to add was encoded into a base64. how can i get the image URL so i can process it using PHP.

My HTML

```
 <div id="editor" name="editor" data-target="content">

</div>

<form>
<textarea type="text"  name="content" id="content"></textarea>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger copyeditor">Save</button>


</form>
```

My jquery and ajax script

```
<script>

$(".copyeditor").on("click", function() {

       var targetName = $("#editor").attr('data-target');
       $('#'+targetName).val($('#editor').html());


       $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "data.php",
  data: $('#content').html(),
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});


    });

</script>
```

Here is what i am dealing with.

[image]

The goal is to make this

```
<img style="width: 640px;" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4Qv6RXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABwESAAMAAAABAAEAAAEaAAUAAAABAAAAYgEbAAUAAAABAAAAagEoAAMAAAABAAIAAAExAAIAAAAeAAAAcgEyAAIAAAAUAAAAkIdp...............>
```

Look like this

```
<img src="/images/blah/blah.jpg.">
```

Comment: What's your limit in php.ini file with key "post_max_size" ? Server may directly refuse that request with that reason.

Comment: Its set to post_max_size=550M

Comment: Ok, so try to use processData: false, in your ajax call params.  And set dataType param to xml or html value. It should helps.

Comment: Tried it, error still the same.

Comment: Ok, so after a hour of looking around i decided to use summernote  WYSIWYG instead and follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27600724/summernote-image-url-instead-of-base64 and use the top answer.