# Summernote - Delete image from server

Tags: php, jquery, html, summernote

Hi I have used the code from the following link to allow images to be uploaded to the server.
[Summernote image upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628222/summernote-image-upload)

Would it be possible to implement something similar to remove an image from the server if a user deletes it from the editor? If so, how can I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 9):

To Delete file form Server, you need to use `onMediaDelete` but usage varies with different summernote versions, sometimes difficult to find in the docs.

**FOR SUMMERNOTE 0.6.x**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.summernote').summernote({
        height: "300px",
         onMediaDelete : function($target, editor, $editable) {
         alert($target.context.dataset.filename);         
         $target.remove();
    }
    });
});
```

**FOR SUMMERNOTE 0.7.x**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.summernote').summernote({
        height: "300px",
        onMediaDelete : function(target) {
                deleteFile(target[0].src);
            }

    });
});
```

**FOR SUMMERNOTE 0.8.x (Use Callbacks)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#summernote').summernote({
        height: "300px",
        callbacks: {
            onImageUpload: function(files) {
                uploadFile(files[0]);
            },

            onMediaDelete : function(target) {
                // alert(target[0].src) 
                deleteFile(target[0].src);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**Javascript : Sample to Delete File using img src**

```
function deleteFile(src) {

    $.ajax({
        data: {src : src},
        type: "POST",
        url: base_url+"dropzone/delete_file", // replace with your url
        cache: false,
        success: function(resp) {
            console.log(resp);
        }
    });
}
```

**PHP: Sample to Delete Image afeter retrieving img src**

```
<?php
  $src = $this->input->post('src'); // $src = $_POST['src'];
  $file_name = str_replace(base_url(), '', $src); // striping host to get relative path
        if(unlink($file_name))
        {
            echo 'File Delete Successfully';
        }
?>
```

[image]

This is what I used, its just that, the delete event is not triggered on keypress like backspace, perhaps a keyEvent will handle that in future.

Comment: Nice solution but, what happens if someone deletes the image by just using the backspace key?, it seems that the callback doesn't trigger...

Comment: @4Jean, I know it's been a while, but it still doesn't work on my site. I'm using summernote-bs4.min.js and download directly from Summernote official website. could you please tell me which version exactly you were using back that moment? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you solved the problem by now but as I have been looking for the same answer and finally managed to make it work here is my approach:

First I get all the `img src` in summernote's `textarea` then I read all the `img` files in the folder on the server. After that, I `unlink` the files in the folder which are not in summernote's img src array.

```
        $dom = new domDocument;
        $dom->loadHTML(html_entity_decode($content));
        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $imgs  = $dom->getElementsByTagName("img");
        $links = array();
        $path = '../content/'.$id.'/';
        $files = glob($path . "*.*");
        for($i = 0; $i < $imgs->length; $i++) {
           $links[] = $imgs->item($i)->getAttribute("src");
        }
        $result=array_diff($files, $links);
           foreach($result as $deleteFile) {
               if (file_exists($deleteFile)) {
                 array_map('unlink', glob($deleteFile));
               }
           }
       }
```

Hope this will help others.

EDIT to answer to @eachone:
You can use AJAX too (I do it with jQuery).

```
$('#DivContainingSummernoteTextarea').blur(function(){
$contentPost = $("#SummernoteTextarea").code();
doAjax('something');
});
```

I store the content of summernote's textarea in `$contentPost`. Then `doAjax` will call the PHP and POST `$content`. If the `img` on the server is not in `$content` it will be deleted.

Comment: where can i find more specific guideline

Answer (score 0):

If we can catch an event for user's deleting image action on the client side, we can make a ajax call for delete image. but I don't know whether it is or not. I also looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Django i am using regex to find imgs in raw html
If i am deleting post, or it has different imgs after editing I am removing them

```
from traceback import print_exc
import re
import os

def get_imgs(html):
    pat = re.compile(r'<img [^>]*src="([^"]+)')
    imgs = pat.findall(html)
    return imgs

def delete_imgs(imgs):
    if imgs:
        base = os.getcwd()
        for img in imgs:
            try:
                img_path = os.path.join(base, img[1:])
                if os.path.exists(img_path):
                    os.remove(img_path)
            except Exception as e:
                print_exc(e)
                print(imgs)
                print(img_path)
```