# Summernote delete images

Tags: javascript, summernote

You know, Summernote is some of powerful text editor and has good documentation about it which means it is easy to use for me. But I couldn't find any docs about how to deleting insertedImages (which drag and drop) with backspace or delete button from keyboard.

I've seen this article [Summernote - Delete image from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078159/summernote-delete-image-from-server) but not very clear for me how I am suppose to do

https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/605 and https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/884 have a same goals that is deleting image from summernote button, not from keyboard.

Is there any ways to do that? is it possible? and what I'm missing?

Comment: Also searching an answer, have you found a solution?

Comment: unfortunately, nope sir :( still struggling at this thing @aznxfrost

Answer (score 0):

The documentation sucks for anything more than the basics. 
Anyway have you tried this:

```
$(".summernote").summernote({
    onMediaDelete : function($target, editor, $editable) {
        console.log($target.context.dataset.filename);         
        $target.remove();
        console.log("all gone!");     
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

summernote does not have this option to control the extension, it accepts all kinds of images, but I needed to release the file uploaded in pdf and found the solution check:

[How to set image extensions for insert image dialog of Summernote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54896263/how-to-set-image-extensions-for-insert-image-dialog-of-summernote/56696777#56696777)

Comment: Add explanation how this solves the original problem.