# Remove file from server Summernote v0.8.18

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, summernote

I am trying to delete file from server in summernote, but always getting undefined src error.

> Warning: Undefined array key "src" in C:\wamp64\www\

I searched around found this: [Summernote - Delete image from server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47182148/12232340) and more but none of them are working.

I tried var `src = $(this).attr("src");` and `.prop()` function no luck to pass url in src to php file.

This is how src url is :`<img src="http://localhost/news/uploads/large/6dBUlfZZBW.webp">`
Here is my setup :

```
   $('#summernote').summernote({
      height: 400,
      callbacks: {
         onImageUpload: function(files, editor, welEditable) {
            sendFile(files[0], editor, welEditable);
         },
         onMediaDelete : function($target) {
             console.log($target[0].src); //This adds full url of src into console on test.

            deleteFile($target[0].src);
            $target.remove();
         }
      }
   });
```

And my delete function :

```
function deleteFile(src) {
   var src = $(this).attr("src");
   $.ajax({     
      data:src,
      type: "POST",
      url: "delete_summernote.php",
      cache: false,
      success: function(resp) {
         console.log(resp);
         console.log(src);
      }
   });
}
```

Simple php example :

```
if(isset($_FILES['src'])){
$url = $_FILES['src'];

        unlink($url);
        
} else {
   echo "Src not set.";
}
```

**Solved :** Just needed a simple function, no cahce, no attr etc. thanks guys.

```
   function deleteFile(path) {
      $.ajax({
         url: "delete.php",
         type: "POST",
         data:  {'path':path},
         success: function(resp) {
            alert(resp);
         }          
      });
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your delete file function has some wrong specifications so that is the reason it is not working.
Correct If I am wrong!

`var src = $(this).attr("src");` // you are specifying to select "src" attribute

But here :
`deleteFile($target[0].src);`
you are selecting source in function then variable src output will be underfined.

This is what I understand.
I hope it will help if I am not wrong But I have tried it on my pc.
But I don't have full code I could help you.

Comment: How did you try ? how to modify this var `src = $(this).attr("src");` full codes are in question.