# Resizing image after insertimage on summernote

Tags: jquery, summernote

I am currently using summernote and have a php fileuploader for it that works great. However, the images inserted can sometimes be really large, 1920x1080 and larger.

Summernote comes with a great "scale" function for images, and i would love to programmatically trigger it.
So when i upload and insert my image it would automatically be scaled down to a given percentage.

I know i can resize the image serverside, but im gonna do a lightbox on the images so i want them in their full size, but scaled down.

Has anyone done something similar?

Comment: I know this is old, but for further reference, I suggested a solution to automatically resize upon insertion (no user intervention). See [issue#2344](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/2344)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem and solved it by creating a plugin for that.

It automatically resizes, flips and rotates images before putting them into the summernote editor.

Download the Resized Data Image Plugin for Summernote [here](https://github.com/raphaelbeckmann/summernote/blob/patch-1/plugin/summernote-ext-resized-data-image.js).

In addition you need [Exif.js](https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js) to read the EXIF data of images.

Also add this CSS Code to your page to make the `input[type=file]` button as an icon button:

```
button[data-name=resizedDataImage] {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

button[data-name=resizedDataImage] input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 200px;
    max-width: 100%;
    -ms-filter: 'alpha(opacity=0)';
    direction: ltr;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Finally add the plugin **resizedDataImage** to your summernote toolbar.

The final setup of your page could look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design/css/summernote.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/exif.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/summernote.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/summernote-ext-resized-data-image.js"></script>  
<style type="text/css">
    button[data-name=resizedDataImage]  {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    button[data-name=resizedDataImage] input {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        font-size: 200px;
        max-width: 100%;
        -ms-filter: 'alpha(opacity=0)';
        direction: ltr;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.summernote').summernote({
            height: 250,
            toolbar: [
                ['insert', ['resizedDataImage', 'link']]
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hey, great stuff! This does what i need and is tweakable :D

Comment: I just updated the code again, now all transformations (flipping and rotating) work properly: [Resized Data Image Plugin for Summernote](https://github.com/raphaelbeckmann/summernote/blob/patch-1/plugin/summernote-ext-resized-data-image.js)

Comment: Any chance of this being updated to take in account the latest changes? https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/1361

Comment: I got `summernote-ext-resized-data-image.self-41628b1……:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTemplate' of undefined`. It seems `$.summernote.renderer` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue using solutions from
(Image Upload for Summernote v0.8.1)
[Summernote image upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628222/summernote-image-upload#answer-22589018)

And using https://github.com/verot/class.upload.php library to verify/resize images

Instead of using the php file in Image for summernote v0.8.1 use this:

```
require_once("pathtoclassfile/src/class.upload.php");
if(!empty($_FILES['image'])){
    $handle = new upload($_FILES['image']);

if ($handle->uploaded) {
    $handle->allowed = array('image/*');
    $handle->mime_check = true; //this is set to true by default
    $handle->no_script = true;  //this is set to true by default
    $handle->forbidden = array('application/*','audio/*','multipart/*','text/*','video/*');
    $name = md5(uniqid()); //generate a new random name for your file
    $handle->file_new_name_body   = $name; 
    $handle->file_auto_rename = true;
    $handle->image_resize         = true;
    $handle->image_x              = 350;  //resize the image to what you want
    $handle->image_ratio_y        = true;
    $handle->image_convert = 'jpg';   //I converted to jpg so that all my extensions are jpg
    $handle->jpeg_quality = 50;   //you can adjust the image quality to resize further
    $handle->process('uploads'); //set the upload path
  if ($handle->processed) {

    $imagename = "$name.jpg"; //attach the extenstion to the file name
    $baseurl = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; //your server host or use "example.com/";
    echo $baseurl.'uploads/summernote/'.$imagename;

    $handle->clean();
      }
}
}
```

Then in your javascript change success function to:

```
success: function(url) {
            if(url !== ''){
            var image = $('<img>').attr('src', 'http://' + url);
            $('#summernote').summernote("insertNode", image[0]);
            }else{
                alert('File is not an image!\nOnly jpg, png, jpeg and gif are allowed');
            }
        },
```

Get the rest of the codes from the links I posted above.

Comment: Nice explanition, this `$handle->file_dst_name;`  handles file name, you can do like this `$baseurl = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];echo $baseurl.'uploads/summernote/'.$handle->file_dst_name;`