# Submit image through angular-summernote

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, summernote

I'm new to summernote. I am developing an SPA using angularjs.
There I have created a form where a question is submitted. So you have an image might be required along with the question text and answers.
My question is how to submit the image also along with the text as json??
I am using ajax jquery post....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Summernote image upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628222/summernote-image-upload)

Comment: You also have a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30257389/summernote-image-upload-and-alternative-not-working)

Comment: ... and most probably [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947705/summernote-image-upload-error)

Comment: There is also a working tutorial [here](http://www.idyllic-software.com/blog/use-of-summernote-wyswig-editor-for-image-upload/)