# How to upload image in summernote editor in Yii2?

Tags: image, yii2, image-uploading, summernote

Can anyone tell me how to upload & store image in summer note in Yii2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per i know when we upload an image in the `summernote` editor, the image is converted into `BLOB(Binary large Object)` and you can store this into a database with your other body text.

Comment: Do I need to write any separate code to store image in db as well as in a folder?Cause when I searched on google ,I found that it is stored by writing a separate ajax function ?

Comment: & How it will be fetched at the time of update if it is not stored anwhere?

Comment: No, no extra code or folder is needed. to understand how it will work at the update time you should practically test the summernote then you will understand better.

Comment: Yes , I 've tried it but image does not populate on update.

Comment: in my case images is populating in its perfect position! did you populate it into the summernote?

Comment: I've set dataType of column to BLOB.Still when I add image , saved & tried to view on update page, it shows blank.When I viewd the code it shows "<p><br></p>". that means image is not saved

Comment: what is stored in the database column when you upload an image?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89642/discussion-between-user2431224-and-md-khairul-islam).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628222/summernote-image-upload
this is may be helpful to you