# Summernote image upload error

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, summernote

I'm using codeigniter, twitter bootstrap and summernote as my WYSIWYG editor. Im facing some problem with the image upload. Whenever uploading an image using Summernote, it serializes the image in a base64 string. That base64 string is so long that it doesnt fit in the text data-type in phpmyadmin. What i want to do is, upload the image using PHP upload function and store its url in the database instead of the base64 string. How would i do that?

With reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628222/summernote-image-upload) post, here's the code,

```
$(function() {
  $('.summernote').summernote({
    height: 100,
    onImageUpload: function(files, editor, welEditable) {
            sendFile(files[0], editor, welEditable);
        }
  });
  function sendFile(file, editor, welEditable) {
        data = new FormData();
        data.append("files", file);
        upload_url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "dashboard/uploader/";
        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: "POST",
            url: upload_url,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(url) {
                editor.insertImage(welEditable, url);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

the uploader method in the dashboard class is where my php upload code resides. Here's the PHP code,

```
public function uploader()
{
    $this->load->helper('file');
    if ($_FILES['files']['name']) {
        if (!$_FILES['files']['error']) {
            $name = md5(rand(100, 200));
            $ext = explode('.', $_FILES['files']['name']);
            $filename = $name . '.' . $ext[1];
            $destination = base_url().'uploads/' . $filename; 
            $location = $_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"];
            move_uploaded_file($location, $destination);
            echo base_url() . $filename; 
        }
        else
        {
          echo  $message = 'Ooops!  Your upload triggered the following error:  '.$_FILES['files']['error'];
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever i upload the image, it doesnt show it in the wysiwyg editor. Where am i going wrong?

now it looks like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('.summernote').summernote({
    height: 100,
    onImageUpload: function(files) {
            sendFile(files[0]);
        }
  });
  function sendFile(file) {
        data = new FormData();
        data.append("files", file);
        upload_url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "dashboard/uploader/";
        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: "POST",
            url: upload_url,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(url) {
                 $(this).summernote("insertImage", url);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35815418/2847436 , this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of summernote are you using? Latest (0.6.16) summernote calls custom `OnImageUpload` function with only one argument - `files`, without `editor` and `welEditable`.

See : 
https://github.com/summernote/summernote/blob/v0.6.16/src/js/EventHandler.js#L117

Please refer the [javascript code of `django-summernote`](https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote/blob/master/django_summernote/templates/django_summernote/widget_inplace.html#L45-L66).

---

Summernote changed its behavior on handling images after 0.6.5. See [changes](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/commit/95299ce2a26eed6601e87cef7fcef724f0420a57).

Comment: so how am i gonna fix it with using editor and welEditable?

Comment: No need to use editor and welEditable. Just like  `$(this).summernote("insertImage", url);` Please refer https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote/blob/master/django_summernote/templates/django_summernote/widget_inplace.html#L45-L66

Comment: also the upload_url = `"<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "dashboard/uploader/";` is the url of the php upload function?

Comment: You're using `$(this)` outside of summernote initialization scope.