# summernote js upload image

Tags: javascript, php, summernote

I'm using summernote version 0.8.1 (current).

It's working. But 1 thing I struggle with. Inserting an image, rather than putting base64 dataURL, I want to upload the image to the server and insert the image URL in the database. This is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#summernote').summernote({
    lang: 'fr-FR',
    height: 300,
    toolbar : [
        ['style',['bold','italic','underline','clear']],
        ['font',['fontsize']],
        ['color',['color']],
        ['para',['ul','ol','paragraph']],
        ['link',['link']],
        ['picture',['picture']]
    ],
    onImageUpload: function(files, editor, welEditable) {
        for (var i = files.lenght - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        sendFile(files[i], this);
        }
    }
});

function sendFile(file, el) {
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('file',file);
    $.ajax ({
        data: form_data,
        type: "POST",
        url: "../up.php",
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(url) {
            $(el).summernote('editor.insertImage',url);
            }
        })
    }

});
    </script>
```

I have tested the script up.php and what that does is changing the file name and returning the image's url in the form "../photos/mypicture.jpg".

The problem with the above code is that the ..up.php doesn't even seem to be called. I ran this in Firefox development tools and got no errors or warnings.

Answer (score 6):

I got it working. Here's my code. Using summernote 0.8.1, i.e. current version.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

var IMAGE_PATH = 'http://www.path/to/document_root/';
                  // the exact folder in the document_root
                  // will be provided by php script below

$('#summernote').summernote({
    lang: 'fr-FR', // <= nobody is perfect :)
    height: 300,
    toolbar : [
        ['style',['bold','italic','underline','clear']],
        ['font',['fontsize']],
        ['color',['color']],
        ['para',['ul','ol','paragraph']],
        ['link',['link']],
        ['picture',['picture']]
    ],
    callbacks : {
        onImageUpload: function(image) {
            uploadImage(image[0]);
        }
    }
});

function uploadImage(image) {
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("image",image);
    $.ajax ({
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        url: "../up.php",// this file uploads the picture and 
                         // returns a chain containing the path
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(url) {
            var image = IMAGE_PATH + url;
            $('#summernote').summernote("insertImage", image);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                }
        });
    }

});
</script>
```

Here my up.php :

```
<?php
require('admchir/nettoie.php'); 
      // nettoie.php removes the French special chars and spaces
$image = nettoie($_FILES['image']['name']);
$uploaddir = 'photos/';
      // that's the directory in the document_root where I put pics
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($image);
if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$uploadfile)) {
    echo$uploadfile;
} else {
    echo "Lo kol kakh tov..."; // <= nobody is perfect :)
}
?>
```

From looking for this on the internet, I got the impression that summernote changed a lot between the various versions, but didn't find a full working example of the current version. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: works great, thanks a lot. Sir, I integrated it with CI 3 with CSRF protection :)

Comment: Cool, worked for me as well. However doesn't this open up attacks by users to just flood your server with images by constantly uploading new ones in the Summernote editor, and deleting them? Is there a way to persist the images only after the blog post or whatever has been saved as well?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I integrated it with `Codeigniter 3`, `Summernote 0.8.1`:

I am posting my working solution here so that anyone else can get some help or idea on how to implement summernote with image upload in CI 3 with CSRF.

the javascript code:

```
<!-- include libraries(jQuery, bootstrap) -->
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script> 

<!-- include summernote css/js-->
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.1/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.1/summernote.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#content').summernote({
        height: 400,
        callbacks: {
            onImageUpload: function (image) {
                sendFile(image[0]);
            }
        }

    });
    function sendFile(image) {
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append("image", image);
        //if you are using CI 3 CSRF
        data.append("<?= $this->security->get_csrf_token_name() ?>", "<?= $this->security->get_csrf_hash() ?>");
        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?= site_url('summernote-image-upload') ?>",
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (url) {
                var image = url;
                $('#content').summernote("insertImage", image);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

the codeigniter part:

```
 //add this line in your routes.php
 $route['summernote-image-upload'] = 'welcome/summernote-image-upload';

 //now add this method in your Welcome.php Controller:
 function summernote_image_upload() {
    if ($_FILES['image']['name']) {
        if (!$_FILES['image']['error']) {
            $ext = explode('.', $_FILES['image']['name']);
            $filename = underscore($ext[0]) . '.' . $ext[1];
            $destination = './public/images/summernote/' . $filename; //change path of the folder...
            $location = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
            move_uploaded_file($location, $destination);
            echo base_url() . 'public/images/summernote/' . $filename;
        } else {
            echo $message = 'The following error occured:  ' . $_FILES['image']['error'];
        }
    }
}
```

the HTML part:

```
   <textarea name="content" id="content"><?= html_entity_decode(set_value('content')) ?></textarea>
   <?= form_error('content') ?>
```

note if you face issue with CSRF (for any reason), then you can exclude the summernote ajax upload in your `config.php` file:

```
 $config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array('summernote-image-upload');
```