# How to upload image in CKEditor from desktop when I am using CKEditor CDN?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter-3

I am using CKEditor from CDN. The CDN code is given bellow. But in the CKEditor I can not upload image from my pc. I have to give link of the image uploaded already in another place or site. The java script CDN is : src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.7/standard/ckeditor.js">

and this is the inistialization of CKEditor:

```
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor' );


        var abc = <?php echo json_encode($x) ?>;
        CKEDITOR.instances.editor.setData(abc);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you are using CKEDITOR when a better mobile friendly [Summer Note](http://summernote.org/) is available for free too.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35815418/2847436

use the above link for image upload using ajax in CI 3 whether you want to upload it from desktop or from any folder.. it will work.. drag and drop supports also available