# Angular - base64 image with ng-model bound textarea performance issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image-uploading, summernote, 2-way-object-databinding

I am working on an app that uses Summernote WYSIWYG wrapped in an angular directive. I am using the default behavior on image upload which is basically encoding the chosen image in base64 and putting that in as an `<img>` tag.

Unfortunately, when testing it, the image does get inserted into the box, however the whole site starts lagging really bad.

The code is basically:

**in CreateController.js:**

```
// This object holds all the post info
self.post = {};
```

**in create-view.html:**

```
// This object holds all the post info
<div id="summernote" summernote ng-model="Create.post.Content" config="Create.snOptions"> </div>
```

(using `CreateController as Create`)

The lag comes from the base64 encoded image included in the `self.post.Content`, that is being updated with the `ng-model` two-way binding every time a letter is typed.

I don't actually need the binding, it's perfectly ok for me to let the user type everything in and then click submit and process it, however I haven't found a way how to push the content of summernote into a method or into `self.post.Content` on submit of the form.

I tried not using `ng-model` and just passing a jQuery selection in the submit button like

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="Create.send(angular.element("#summernote").html()">Send Report</button>`
```

however this selection returns nothing, as there are some more complex DOM elements in the summernote directive ([Creator's JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/outsider/n8dt4/314/embedded/result%2Chtml%2Cjs%2Ccss/))

Does anyone have any clue what I should do?

Thanks!

Comment: Write a custom function for `onImageUpload` as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628222/summernote-image-upload#answer-22589018 then manually process (base64 encode) the `img src` attributes on form submit.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Can you elaborate ? What do you mean by "manually process"? and Why would I need to make a custom `onImageUpload` ? The uploaded image gets encoded to base64 fine, the problem is in the databinding watcher that slows everything down.

And even if I make a function that gets called on form submit, one of my problems as I have mentioned is that I cannot quite find a way how to extract the contents from summernote inside of that function.

Comment: You can't rely on Summernote WYSIWYG to serialize the images because it does so every time you change the content. So you need to disable that somehow. As far as I understand, overriding `onImageUpload` is the way to do that. Next step you'll need to do the serialization yourself before saving.

Comment: I assume you think the summernote code is re-encoding the image on each $digest of Angular. I do not understand why would that be the case, the image has already been encoded and there's a fully working base 64 img tag inside of summernote's textarea. I don't think the `onImageUpload` will get triggered again unless I try to upload another image.

Comment: But then some processing done by Summernote is triggered by $digest and is causing the lag, that's what you described at least. if it's not the images then it's something else. I'm also guessing you won't be able to use `ng-model` on it but will have to come up with your own solution.